# Protobuf converts message to pointer

Tags: go, pointers, protocol-buffers

I have a program like this ->

`message Action{ }`

`message Person{ Action action = 1; }`

I want the action field in Person to be converted to a non pointer struct in golang. But after
compiling it converts to ->

`type Person struct{ action *Action }`

PS: I am using proto3.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct and desired.

Protocol Buffers includes an optimization in which default values (e.g. int of 0, bool of false) are dropped from the on-the-wire messages because these values may be assumed by the recipient (and ommitting them saves space and processing).

> **Corollary**: if the client doesn't include an int, bool when these values are expected, the server assumes the int is zero and the bool is false and vice versa.

This behavior extends to structs (in Go which result from `protoc`'s compilation of messages) because there's no concept of null in Go (which would be the equivalent of a default value).

To perpetuate this default value behavior, messages are always compiled to pointers to structs in Go such that a nil pointer is the default value (and not included on-the-wire).

There's no way around this behavior using `protoc`.

An example may help. I'm using a slight variant of your example to prove the point:

`foo.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "77857807/protos";

message Action {}

message Person {
  int32 id = 1;
  optional Action action = 2;
}
```

And:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    pb "77857807/protos"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

func main() {
    for _, p := range []*pb.Person{
        nil,
        {},
        {Id: 0},
        {Id: 1},
        {Id: 2, Action: nil},
        {Id: 3, Action: &pb.Action{}},
    } {
        {
            b, _ := protojson.Marshal(p)
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
        }
        {
            b, _ := proto.Marshal(p)
            fmt.Printf("%x\n", b)
        }
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
# Person is nil
{}

# Person is empty
{}

# Person contains an Id of 0 (default)
{}

# Person contains Id and Action is omitted (default)
{"id":1}
0801

# Person contains Id and Action is nil (default)
{"id":2}
0802

# Person contains Id and Action is something
{"id":3,"action":{}}
08031200
```

Notice how the JSON matches expectations but the on-the-wire protobuf messages exclude default values